# Variable URL redirects by value of html contact form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Due to the requirement of our CRM, I have to deal with a very basic html contact form (short version):

```
<form id="contact_form" method="POST" name="contact_form">
<p><strong>Select the white paper you would like to have:</strong></p>
<label for="paper" class="mandatory">
  <span>White paper<select id="paper" name="paper" required>
    <option selected="selected" value="">-Please select-</option>
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
  </select>
</label>
<input id="redirect_url" type="hidden" name="redirect_url" value="" />
<input class="download" onclick="submit_form();" type="submit" value="Download" />
</form>
```

Is there any possibility to write a variable into `redirect_url` specified by `value`?

A= "http://example.com/a" / B= "http://example.com/b" etc.

Should I try `jQuery var` or `document.getElementById`?

Very basic question, I know, but I recently started my ambitions towards Javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery:

```
var newURL = "http://example.com/b";
$("#redirect_url").val(newURL);
```

Javascript:

```
var newURL = "http://example.com/b";
document.getElementById("redirect_url").value = newURL;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I decided to proceed with jQuery but now I'm stuck within the definition of the if and else queue. Wrote a short function `wp_request` that executives `onchange` and gives back the selected value: `$("form").wp_request(function() {
$('#paper').children('option:selected').val();` but I can't figure out how to implement your variable definition afterwards.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance! Posted another question with comprehensive explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45812619/jquery-variable-redirect-for-html-contact-form